# Are incorporeal creatures damaged by the Dreamheart Tempest?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, planes, damage-types, incorporeal

Incorporeal creatures are only damaged by magical effects (50% of the time), force damage, other incorporeal things, and things specifically designed to interact with incorporeal creatures (e.g. Ghost Touch weapons).

The Dreamheart is, well, the heart of the Plane of Dreams, and as far as I can tell is mostly covered by the Dreamheart Tempest, an ambient storm of energy that does 5 damage of each elemental type (fire, acid, cold, lightning, and sonic) every turn to a character that hasn't found shelter.

**How do these two things interact?**

Take the Dream Vestige (Libris Mortis), an incorporeal undead that can enter the Plane of Dreams at will. Is it immune to the Tempest because it's not called out as a magical effect, just an ambient part of the landscape? Or is elemental damage magical by default, and the Vestige risks being shredded every time it ventures too deep into the plane?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Weather effects certainly *can be* magical, but they have to label themselves as such. Unlabeled environmental effects are non-magical by default. And elemental damage can certainly be non-magical—fires deal fire damage, extremely cold substances can deal cold damage, lightning deals electricity damage, acid and other caustic or corrosive substances deal acid damage, and earthquakes can deal sonic damage. So the Dreamheart Tempest is non-magical in nature, and does not affect incorporeal creatures.

It is the nature of the planes to exhibit phenomena we would consider impossible in reality, and yet not consider those things magical. *Antimagic field* doesn’t protect you from the penalties associated with being a conflicting alignment on an aligned plane, for example; those penalties are non-magical. Remember:

> Extraordinary abilities are nonmagical, though they may break the laws of physics.

Answer (score -3):

I would say that any effect of a non-Material Plane would be considered magical by nature.  I have no sourcebook to back this up, just what seems to make sense.  The alignment, elemental, and energy damage taken from other Planes all seem to be magical in nature, overcoming damage reduction and requiring spells/magical items to protect against it.